# Testing levels/groups in PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

We already have some PHPUnit tests implemented on our codebase.  However, moving forward, in the interest of minimizing the time required to run tests, I'd like to separate out our tests into two groups, or levels:

1. Tests that are very low-level and don't hit the test database (unit tests)
2. Tests that are higher level and interact with the test database (sometimes called component or integration tests)

This would allow us to just run the level 1 test when working on basic functionality, while running both level 1 and 2 when working on higher-level functionality, or before committing to the main line/build.

How would I go about accomplishing this with PHPUnit?

Comment: Since we're using PHPUnit, our tests are written in plain ol' PHP.  I suppose one thought is to define() a constant before the tests run, specifying the desired "test level".  All tests could be written such that if they were above the requested run level, they would just return true.

Comment: Looks like we could also use the `filter` command-line option: `--filter <pattern> Filter which tests to run.`  If we append, for example, either "Unit" or "Integration" to our test names, we could ostensibly use the `filter` option to specify "Unit", "Integration", or neither.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

@Schleis' answer is entirely correct and very useful.  The only catch (which I admittedly didn't include in my question) is that I'd like to be able to scatter Unit and Integration tests throughout our test files - I want to avoid having two files of tests - one file for Unit tests for SomeClass, and a separate file for Functional tests, also for SomeClass.

The PHPUnit command-line option that I found that enables this is [groups](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions):

`--group
Only runs tests from the specified group(s). A test can be tagged as belonging to a group using the @group annotation.`

To use this approach, you simply add the `@group` annotation to the multiline comment before your tests as such:

```
class SomeClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    /**
     * @group Unit
     */
    public function testSomeUnitFunctionality() {
        $this->assertEquals(xyz(' .a1#2 3f4!', true), ' 12 34');
    }

    /**
     * @group Integration
     */
    public function testSomeIntegrationFunctionality() {
        $this->assertEquals(xyz(' .a1#2 3f4!', true), ' 12 34');
    }
}
```

This allows me to do the following:

- `phpunit --group Unit` (Just unit tests)
- `phpunit --group Integration` (Just integration tests)
- `phpunit` (All tests)

Comment: Another nice benefit of using this approach is that `The @author annotation is an alias for @group allowing to filter tests based on their authors.` (http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions)

Comment: Is there a way to include/exclude certain groups from a test-suite via phpunit.xml configuration? you think this should be easy, cannot figure it out.

Comment: don't mix unit and integration tests! EVER

Comment: @clockw0rk Why? phpunit is perfectly capable of running both unit and integration tests. This approach separates the unit and integration tests into separate groups. What is the harm of "mixing" these separate groups? If you're instead arguing that phpunit shouldn't be used to write integration tests, then that's a more valid criticism, but that's not quite what you said.

Comment: sure, there are better options for integration tests, but what i meant was that there should be a dedicated structure for unittests including mockobjects, and a dedicated structure for integration tests including bootstrapping and destructing. take care not to delete half of your database by mistaking mock and integrationtest objects!

Answer (score 15):

You can write a `phpunit.xml` that will seperate your tests into test suites that you can run separately.

http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests.xml-configuration

It would look similar to:

```
<phpunit>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Unit_Tests">
      <directory>SomeTests</directory>
      <directory>MoreTests</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Functional_Tests">
      <directory>OtherTests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Then when you want to run only one group of tests you would call `phpunit --testsuite Unit_Tests` or `phpunit --testsuite Functional_Tests` as needed.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response!  The only problem is that I'd like to keep the unit tests and integration tests for a given PHP source file (e.g. src/example.php) in the same test file (e.g. test/example.php).  Do you know if this approach would lend itself well to including/excluding specific tests in a file?

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to groups is to use a naming convention:

```xml
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="unit-tests">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">test</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="benchmark">
            <directory suffix="Benchmark.php">test</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
```

Files like `test/SomethingTest.php` (`class SomethingTest extends TestCase {...}`) are in the `unit-test` suite and files like `test/SomeBenchmark.php` (`class SomeBenchmark extends TestCase {...}`) are in the `benchmark` suite.

It is simple, obvious and practical.

It also allows us to have `test/SomeExperiment.php` (`class SomeExperiment extends TestCase {...}`) that is not part of either suite (and thus it won't fail in a CI pipeline), but it still can be executed explicitly during development.